# Generic C# method with type constraint does not compile

Tags: c#, generics, types, constraints

I have an extension method with a generic type constraint. To my surprise, this code does not compile.

```cs
namespace N
{
    public interface M
    {
    }

    public class X : M
    {
        public static void DoSomething()
        {
            var x = new X();
            // ERROR: CS0407 'M X.DoSomethingWith(M)' has the wrong return type
            x.Configure(DoSomethingWith);
        }

        private static M DoSomethingWith(M obj)
        {
            return obj;
        }
    }

    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static T Configure<T>(this T obj, Func<T, T> action) where T : M
        {
            return action(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

A similar construct, with a `void`-typed extension method, does compile:

```cs
    public interface M
    {
    }

    public class X : M
    {
        public static void DoSomething()
        {
            var x = new X();

            // compiles fine
            x.Configure(DoSomethingWith);
        }

        private static void DoSomethingWith(M obj)
        {
        }
    }

    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static void Configure<T>(this T obj, Action<T> action) where T : M
        {
        }
    }
```

What is happening here and why is the first version not valid?

Comment: Just change the call to `x.Configure<M>(DoSomethingWith);`. Basically I suspect type inference is inferring `T=X` due to the call to `x.Configure`, and that doesn't work with the delegate. I'd need to spend about an hour with the spec to go through all the steps involved, but that's the basics of it.

Comment: Also the one with the `Action<T>` works because `Action<T>` is contravariant as in you can pass a `X` to something that takes a `M` where as the `Func<T, T>` is invariant because you cannot return an `X` when you expect an `M`.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to the [variance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-delegates) support in delegates for matching method signatures:

> This means that you can assign to delegates not only methods that have matching signatures, but also methods that return more derived types (covariance) or that accept parameters that have less derived types (contravariance) than that specified by the delegate type. This includes both generic and non-generic delegates.

`x.Configure(DoSomethingWith)` will be resolved at compile time as `Configure<X>` and the input parameter of [`Action<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=net-6.0) (and [`Func<T,TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=net-6.0) also) is [contravariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/using-variance-for-func-and-action-generic-delegates#using-delegates-with-contravariant-type-parameters) (i.e. since `X` is `M` it is fine to up-cast it for `DoSomethingWith`) while the return type of `DoSomethingWith` is not guaranteed to be `X` (for `Func<T,TResult>` case).

There are multiple solutions, for example you can explicitly specify generic type parameter for `Configure` as `M`:

```cs
x.Configure<M>(DoSomethingWith);
```

Or change signature of `Configure`:

```cs
private static X DoSomethingWith(X obj) => return obj;
```

Note that changing only return type of `DoSomethingWith` will also work due to the variance in the delegates (though may not fit your desired logic):

```cs
private static X DoSomethingWith(M obj) => obj as X ?? new X();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you "action" in Configure is of type Func<T, T>, which means that we receive T and return T. The factual type of T is X, not M. Method "DoSomething" returns in fact M, which cannot be casted implicitly to X, because X is more specific type. So what C# tries to do with your expression is to find a method "DoSomething", which accepts X and returns X, and there is no such method.